# Form validation with AJAX - preventing from blank fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have some script in JS which should validate my form. It shows information like 'sent' or 'loading' when processing. I'd like to add one more feature. I want to prevent users from sending an e-mail with blank fields. What should I add to the code below to achieve this?

```
$(function() {
  var form = $('#form');
  var submit = $('#submit');

  form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: form.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
      document.getElementById("submit").value = "Loading...";
      },
      success: function() {
      form.trigger('reset');
      document.getElementById("submit").value = "Message sent!";
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use a server-side method `empty()`, should the user disable JS. *Just my 2 cents* ;-)

Comment: Why not just use the quick-and-dirty `required` attribute? http://jsfiddle.net/rcm0x0j3/ - I am going to also throw my vote in with @Fred-ii- for the server side validation.

Comment: I tried with this attribute, but what should I do to add for example captcha? I can't add this attribute to div with captcha code inside.

Comment: Is the captcha being entered in an input field?

Comment: `required` is not enough @BuddhistBeast because JavaScript on the client side can override it. You must also do server-side validation.

Comment: @JayBlanchard They did agree to mine ;-) Gotta love a Plan-b, right *Sam?*

Comment: As long as you are using jQuery, take a look at this plugin: http://ericleads.com/h5validate/ you can use the form validation from HTML5 and the plugins makes the fallback for browsers that didn't implement form validation.

Comment: I use Plan B as Plan A and visey-versey *Ralph* ;-) @Fred-ii-

Comment: I failed to read your second sentence @BuddhistBeast, apologies.

Comment: But, what if Plan A **is** Plan B? Ah, as opposed to *"to be, or not to be"*, that *Sam*, is the question! @JayBlanchard

Comment: Then D *Ralph*..."All of the Above". Unless of course it is "None of the Above" @Fred-ii- Which, coincidentally, is the problem that I have on my hands with a large *ornery* JS object that refuses to give up its goods! I may have to *shoot that varmint!*

Comment: Just yank at 'dem horns *Sam*, and you're likely to get rid of the "bull" @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HTML attribute `required` on the fields that cannot be empty

```
<input type="text" required/>
```

**AND/OR**

Have some javascript check before you submit

```
$(function() {
  var form = $('#form');
  var submit = $('#submit');

  form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('input', this).val().trim() == ''){
       //handle error message
    }
    else{
      $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById("submit").value = "Loading...";
        },
        success: function() {
        form.trigger('reset');
        document.getElementById("submit").value = "Message sent!";
        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**AND/OR**

You do server side checking to make sure the value is not empty
in PHP:

```
if(empty($_POST['input_name'])){
   //handle error
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `submit value`?

Comment: I meant the text which is shown inside the submit button. But nevermind, thanks for your reply.